# Intuition behind retracts

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

I am studying algebraic topology at the moment and we just started with introducing a bunch of definitions that we will use throughout the course. One of those definitions is:

> Definition: Let $A\subset B$ be topological spaces, a map $r:B\to A$ is called a retract if $r|_A=id_A$. We say $A$ is a retraction of $B$.

Here $id_A$ stands for the identity on $A$.
The definition is clear to me but I am lacking intuition maybe because the only example we have seen is the retract to a single point.

Can someone maybe give some more examples with explanation on what is going on, so that I can understand this concept better intuitively. Thank!

Comment: It's a map to a subspace that leaves every point in the subspace fixed. You can find retracts basically by finding maps to a subspace that don't move it around.  This isn't always possible. If you like algebra, this is equivalent to finding a map that induces a homomorphism on your favorite invariant $H_i,\pi_i$ that has a section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another example: the circle $S^1$ is a retract of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$: consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}r\colon&\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&v&\mapsto&\frac1{\|v\|}v.\end{array}$$The idea is that you can (in a continuous way) make the whole space $B$ collapse into $A$ in such a way that no element of $A$ is affected (that is, each element of $A$ is mapped into itself).

Comment: Great explanation! Thank u sir! One more question on the side is there like a strategy to find a retract? Or is that just experience?

Comment: It's mainly experience and geometric intuition. Here's another example: try to prove that $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\geqslant1\}$ is also a retract of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Would that be $x \to \frac{x}{\|x\|^2}$? Thank u for the example and exercise! :)

Comment: No. That doesn't work since, for instance, it maps $(1,1)$ into $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$. What I had in mind was $x\mapsto\frac x{\min\{\|x\|,1\}}$.

Comment: I see very helpful example thanks! :)